# Query with WHERE clause cannot be used with incrementing/timestamp mode

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka connect (Confluent 7.2.1) with JDBC (Confluent jdbc 10.5). I'm using the source connector to read data from a view. The view is prepared to return the id (increment) and the last-modified field (timestamp).
My source database is informix. The destination is PostgreSQL although it is beside the point.

The beginning believed that it worked well since the insertions and modifications made them fast, but when the view increased its data (23 million records) the modifications were no longer instantaneous.

Doing tests I noticed that Kafka connect was actually re-reading the entire view and not just the data starting from the last id and last_date.
To test, I limited the view to 100 records and indeed the changes were detected quickly, when I reconfigure it with the 23 million records it takes hours.

Reviewing a little more I see that the current values are shown like this:

```
rowtime: 2023/01/04 15:27:16.361 Z, key: ["source_novedades",{"query":"query"}], value: {"timestamp_nanos":0,"incrementing":5001,"timestamp":1672835217000}, partition: 2
```

I don't quite understand what timestamp_nano means but nevertheless I see a single date (timestamp) and it is the last one processed.

On the other hand, the query in the log is shown like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_vw WHERE last_date < ? AND (( last_date = ? AND id > ?) OR last_date > ?) ORDER BY last_date, id ASC
```

Which wouldn't make much sense since I'm asking:

```
last_date < ? and also AND (.... OR last_date > ?)
```

- So timestamp=1672860963000 is replaced in all date fields (?)? because if so it clearly wouldn't work.
- Should I do something so that timestamp_nanos=0 is no longer 0 and takes the last processing date?

This is my source connector:

```
    {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:informix-sqli://ip:port/testdb:informixserver=mibase",
        "connection.user":"informix", 
        "connection.password":"pass",
        "query": "SELECT * FROM my_vw",
        "topic.prefix": "novedades",
        "poll.interval.ms": "10000",
        "mode":"timestamp+incrementing",
        "schema.pattern": "informix",
        "timestamp.column.name": "last_date",
        "incrementing.column.name": "id",
        "validate.non.null": false,

        "numeric.mapping":"best_fit",
        "transforms": "copyFieldToKey,extractKeyFromStruct,removeKeyFromValue",
        "transforms.copyFieldToKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
        "transforms.copyFieldToKey.fields": "id",
        "transforms.extractKeyFromStruct.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
        "transforms.extractKeyFromStruct.field": "id",
        "transforms.removeKeyFromValue.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
        "transforms.removeKeyFromValue.blacklist": "id",
        "key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.LongConverter",

        "batch.size": 200000,
        "linger.ms": 60000,
        "compression.type":"lz4",
        "acks": 1,
        "offset.flush.timeout.ms": 300000

}
```

Comment: I think you can remove `query`. By default, it will select all columns.

Comment: @OneCricketeer You mean don't use query and specify only the table? If you mean that, it's not possible, since I'm using informix, the only way it works is using the GenericDialect and it works only with queries.